# What are the system requirements for vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

What are the system requirements for vscode?

The [download page](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) only shows the different platforms this is available on, but doesn't mention any requirements  such as Windows version (i know it doesn't work on XP) or additional required components, such as the .NET framework.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not Microsoft customer support.

Comment: it kind of is. : )

Answer (score 5):

System requirements for VSCode are available [on the documentation page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/requirements).

In a nutshell, VSCode now is self contained for Linux, Mac and Windows. There is a complete list for the additional helpful tools available [on the setup page](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I could argue with the same logic, any information provided in this answer can become out of date, whereas the setup docs page in the website will always contain the required information to get you up and running.

Comment: You can always mention  "as of today / currently" and then point to the link that may contain more recent information. People generally leave a comment when the information gets updated or may even edit your question to include the latest information.

Comment: problem is, the setup page doesn't answer the question of system requirements. so, there is no answer at all in this answer. no offence meant, thanks for trying, but, again, this doesn't answer the question at all. (and i did also ask for the sys req through uservoice.)

Comment: Note taken wazz, we will be explicit on setting up the system requirements for VSCode. This will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

It's not listed in their requirements, but you'll also need a decent video card. It may seem ridiculous, since it's mainly displaying text, but vscode's GPU hardware requirement is well beyond what other applications require. There is a switch `--disable-gpu` to switch it to software rendering but it's still laggy.

Answer (score 0):

As of Version 1.32

- 1.6 GHz or faster processor with 1 GB RAM recommended
- OS X Yosemite
- Windows 7 (with .NET Framework 4.5.2), 8.0, 8.1 and 10 (32-bit and 64-bit)
- Linux with GLIBCXX version 3.4.15 or later, GLIBC version 2.15 or later, tested with Linux (Debian): Ubuntu Desktop 14.04, Debian 7, Linux (Red Hat): Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7, CentOS 7, Fedora 23

Answer (score 0):

You can find the official documentation about this at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/requirements. Quoting the main parts:

> ### Hardware
>
> Visual Studio Code is a small download (< 200 MB) and has a disk footprint of < 500 MB. VS Code is lightweight and should easily run on today's hardware.
>
> We recommend:
>
> - 1.6 GHz or faster processor
> - 1 GB of RAM
>
> ### Platforms
>
> VS Code is supported on the following platforms:
>
> - Windows 10 and 11 (64-bit)
> - macOS versions with Apple security update support. This is typically the latest release and the two previous versions.
> - Linux (Debian): Ubuntu Desktop 18.04, Debian 10
> - Linux (Red Hat): Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7, CentOS 7, Fedora 35

You can find a list of things that aren't supported, and additional Linux requirements in that official document.

You can often find end-of-platform-support notices in the release notes just by searching for "has ended". Ex. Google searching "[`site:code.visualstudio.com/updates "support has ended"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Acode.visualstudio.com%2Fupdates+%22support+has+ended%22)"

- https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_85#_macos-1013-and-1014-support-has-ended
- https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_79#_windows-8-and-81-support-has-ended
- https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_76#_macos-1011-and-1012-support-has-ended
- https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_71#_windows-7-support-has-ended