# How can I use VS Code on versions of macOS that are not supported by the latest version of VS Code?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, download, macos-high-sierra

on the Homepage of VS Code, it is only visible to download it for devices with macOS Catalina (10.15). My question would be if it's possible to download it for older generations especially macOS High Sierra (10.13).

Comment: related: [What are the system requirements for vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29973717/11107541)

Answer (score 2):

[VS Code's platform support doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/requirements#_platforms) says:

> VS Code is supported on the following platforms: [...] macOS versions with Apple security update support. This is typically the latest release and the two previous versions.

If you want support for a macOS version that isn't supported by the latest release of VS Code, you'll have to install an older release of VS Code that *does* support your OS version (see [How to downgrade vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49346733/11107541)).

Answer (score 0):

My best suggestion would be to try out vscodium, vscode isn't technically open source, it's built by microsoft and has some proprietary components like the logos (which are copyrighted). Vscodium is open source and directly built from the git repo of vscode, you could probably find a download for your version of MacOS, it can be a little tricky to install extensions but the program itself should work.

Comment: and this solves the problem... how?